# BIRT: Staggered values on X-Axis in a chart

Tags: charts, birt

I have a chart showing a large time period on the X-Axis (about a year or so). The unit is a day, so only a small part of the labels for these values are visible. I checked the "Stagger" checkbox to display them on two lines, but on the second line only values consecutive to the ones on the upper line are displayed. Thus the distances between the dates displayed are very uneven. For example:

```
Upper line: May 1, 2010
Lower line: May 2, 2010
Upper line: June 10, 2010
Lower line: June 11, 2010
Upper line: July 20, 2010
```

I want the distance between them to be more even:

```
Upper line: May 1, 2010
Lower line: May 20, 2010
Upper line: June 10, 2010
Lower line: June 30, 2010
Upper line: July 20, 2010
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edit Chart window, X-Axis section click on Scale button and specify a step interval or a fixed number of steps.

I couldn't test it, give it a try and good luck!

**If this options are disabled** try setting the Type field to "DateTime" (or something that isn't "Text") and unchecking "Is Cathegory Axis". This should enable Scale options.